# Tracing through recursive LCA Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Can someone please help me trace through this code. I'm having a hard time visualizing the back to back recursive calls.

```
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (root == p || root == q) {
        return root;
    }

    TreeNode l = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left,p,q);
    TreeNode r = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right,p,q);

    if (l != null && r != null){
        return root;
    }

    return l != null ? l:r;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so].Please check [ask]

Comment: What is your question or doubt?

Answer (score 0):

The two calls to lowestCommonAncestor are just traversing the tree to the left and then back up to the right in the tree, this is known as depth first search.
[DFS node order](https://medium.com/basecs/breaking-down-breadth-first-search-cebe696709d9)